# Onclickitem and start new intent inside Cursor

Tags: java, android

I am a new guy to android development. I have created a SMS Inbox application.
I managed to get the SMS Inbox of the phone. Now I want to set a onclick method to open a specific message in a new activity with the phone number and the message.

Here is the code for my inbox activity. I do not understand, the place to put my onclicklistitem method.

```
public class MessageInboxActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private static MessageInboxActivity inst;
ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView smsListView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public static MessageInboxActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_inbox);
    smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_adapter_item, R.id.product_name, smsMessagesList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    refreshSmsInbox();

}

public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());


}

public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try {
        String[] smsMessages = smsMessagesList.get(pos).split("\n");
        String address = smsMessages[0];
        String smsMessage = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; ++i) {
            smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
        }

        String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
        smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
        Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Can someone help me to start new activity with the phone number and the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this in a comment but I can't comment, can you clarify your problem? What activity are you trying to link to and what exactly do you want to achieve? it seems like you just need to add to your onItemClick()

```
    String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
    smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext,/*whatever activity you want to open*/);
    in.putStringExtra(/*some static keystring*/,smsMessage);
    startActivity(in);
```

but it's hard to say for sure without knowing more

Comment: I want open a new activity, when I click on of the messages. I want to parse the senders number and the message body to the new activity.

Comment: okay, well above code should start new activity if I'm reading your listener right. call getIntent() in that activity to get your intent and getStringExtra(keystring) to extract your smsMessageStr for parsing.